# Read an xlsx file and write xml

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, elementtree

I need your help please, I'm trying to write python code, where in input I take an xlsx I read the various fields of the cells and then generate an xml. I had trouble reading dates, so I used pandas, so I could use dataframes, now you give her a handful, I also read the test data, but I am not succeeding in writing this data within XML; can you please help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import json
import datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

df = pd.read_excel('parser.xlsx') #leggo il file excel
df['data autorizzazio'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data autorizzazio'])
#df['data movimentazio'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data menter code hereovimentazio'])

#df.head()
#df.info()


ET.register_namespace("CBIPaymentRequest","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

root = ET.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}CBIPaymentRequest")
root1 = ET.SubElement(root,"GrpHdr") 
#root2 = ET.SubElement(root,"PmtInf")
 
MsgId = ET.SubElement(root1,'MsgId')
MsgId = df.loc[0].values[1]#setto il valore della cella interessata
MsgId.text = df['data autorizzazio'].values[1]
#MsgId = MsgId
print(MsgId)

Prova = ET.SubElement(root1,'PROVA')
Prova = df.loc[0].values[5]
Prova1 = df.__setitem__(Prova,'Prova')
#Prova.text = df['Saluto5'].values[1]
print(Prova)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("pandas_output_test_1.xml")
```

Comment: Is there a specific error you're getting? At least post the current output and desired output in your question.

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

at the moment I generate this xml(unfortunately empty)

```
<CBIPaymentRequest:CBIPaymentRequest xmlns:CBIPaymentRequest="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <GrpHdr>
       <MsgId/>
       <PROVA/>
     </GrpHdr>
</CBIPaymentRequest:CBIPaymentRequest>
```

I wish it was populated with data I read in xlsx file